# Python, not sure why custom imports aren't working when environment variables seem right

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, path, importerror

[image: My Setup]

I think what I have is correct. I have only one version of python on my computer. Python 2.7.6. I built a group of modules and put them into SILO3 folder, then threw that folder into C:\Python27 (which is in the path), yes for some reason I cannot import the first (or any) library from SILO3.

What do I need to understand? I think my environment variables are correct.

Comment: The screenshot is too big to be legible but the smaller thumbnail at least gives us an idea what will be loaded when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You named your *main script* `SILO3.py`. Python finds that first, you'll have to rename the script, it masks the package.

You can see this in your traceback; `Desktop\SILO3.py` imported `Desktop\SILO3.py`, which doesn't find `CheckTruth` in itself:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SILO3.py", line 10, in <module>
    from SILO3 import CheckTruth
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SILO3.py", line 10, in <module>
    from SILO3 import CheckTruth
ImportError: cannot import name CheckTruth
```

Note the `File` lines; they tell you exactly what code where triggered the exception. `SILO3.py` imported `SILO3.py` *in the exact same location*. The exception tells you that Python found *a* `SILO3` package or module, but that the name `CheckTruth` was not available at that location.

You could also diagnose this by asking the imported module for it's file location:

```
import SILO3
print SILO3.__file__
```

and verify that what was imported was what you expected to be imported.

Comment: I just changed the name to SILO V3.py but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @user1367204: Is there a `SILO.pyc` file still there? If you are getting the *same `NameError` exception* then Python is finding *a* `SILO` module that isn't your package. What does `import SILO`, then `print SILO.__file__` print?

Answer (score 0):

Python searches for modules in the paths specified in `sys.path`. 
The `%PATH%` environment variable is unrelated to the module search path.

You can use the [`%PYTHONPATH%`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable to specify custom search paths. However, that is often not necessary.

Put your module in the same directory as the script that is importing it. The current directory is in the default python path.

i.e.:

```
c:\some-folder\SILOV3.py
c:\some-folder\SILO3\
c:\some-folder\SILO3\__init__.py
c:\some-folder\SILO3\CheckTruth.py
```

Also, as @Martijn Pieters mentioned, a file named SILO3.py is a module, so if you have a folder module with the same name, you won't be able to import it.

Comment: The traceback is pretty damning here; the script is importing itself.

Comment: Yes, and it seems there's a bit of confusion around environment variables.

Comment: @user1367204: if putting the script in the same directory worked, then  you still had a local module in the old location masking the package. Most likely that was a `.pyc` file.